# Fixed div no matter which browser size

Tags: css, browser, html, margin

I have a little image, with some decoration, that I need to stick to the top-right corner of my page. But no matter how many different types of code I've used, I can't get it right.

It's sort of like the "Welcome to Q&A for professional.." on top of this page, it stays there no matter how far down I scroll.

I just need to do this with a  containing an image, that sticks to the right-margin of the browser, even if i resize.

You can look at the website http://dawtano.com/pp/ and see the image, that's currently in the middle of the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the gravity of the background to `right top`.

```
#deco {
    background: url("images/header-deco.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    height: 375px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `{background-position: right top;}` to the background image.

Answer (score 1):

If i unsterstand your question correct:
Use position: fixed and top, right in your css

Oh, it´s a background-image...
Use background-position:right top;

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean for the #deco div. If so, based on your current example, this should work:

```
<style>
  background-image: url(images/header-deco.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 599px; /*you must give an actual width here instead of auto*/
  height: 375px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
</style>
```